# Nested conditional in PHP Wordpress loop not working

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, conditional-statements

I am not too familiar with PHP. I want to insert a conditional statement into the WP loop so that for every third post a new div is created and the post is inserted into that div. Here is the code I have so far:

```
    <?php $x = 0; ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (($x == 0) || ($x % 3 == 0)) ?>
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_1_of_3"> //column is 1/3 of the page
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $x += 1; ?>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I am testing it out with 4 posts and instead of creating one three-column section with the first three posts and then beginning the next section, I am getting four separate sections. Potentially trivial mistake but I cannot seem to figure it out!

Comment: Post your output please

Comment: Note that `0 % 3 === 0` so your condition can be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your logic a bit as now you are showing the contents and the opening and closing of your section in the same block.

Apart from that you have a bug: As you don't have `:` or `{` after your inner `if` statement, it has become just an empty statement.

You need something like:

```
<div class="section group">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php if ($x > 0 && $x % 3 === 0): ?>
                                   ^ very important
     </div>
     <div class="section group">
  <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="col span_1_of_3"> //column is 1/3 of the page
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php $x += 1; ?>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Now you only close and open a new section if your inner `if` is matched and the condition actually works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug. There was one extra 'endif' but after removing that it works fine.

Comment: @chidumaga You're right, I removed it just in case.